# Displaying a multi value column (person or group field) in CQWP

Tags: sharepoint-designer, content-query-web-part, item-styles

I can return person or group column(I have selected this field to allow multiple values - People Only) like this "Name1;#24;#Name2;#34".
How can I return something like this
Name 1, Name 2 etc..

I came across this [here](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=spxslt) but it stated it does not work if values did not start with a numeric value which in my case it didn't

Any ideas how to replace ";#' in xsl?

As you can see in my screenshot i can't get to get person.id and person.title at the sametime :(

[image]

```
<xsl:variable name="Person">



    <xsl:value-of select="@Person.title" disable-output-escaping="yes"></xsl:value-of>

       </xsl:variable>

       <xsl:variable name="Personid">

       <xsl:value-of select="@Person.id"></xsl:value-of>

       </xsl:variable>
```

The @person.title returns Peter James;#33;#Andrew Field.
How can i get the output Peter James,Andrew Field

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: Where are you returning the column? Is it in SP Designer via workflow. If so then the solution is to change the Return field as: from "As String to" to "Text"